# Is there a way I can create a event embed with discord js

Tags: javascript

Console just tells me I received one or more errors and
"return errors.length === 0 ? Result.ok(transformed) : Result.err(new CombinedPropertyError(errors));"

```
client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
        interaction.reply('pong')
    } else

        if (interaction.commandName === 'event') {
            const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle } = require('discord.js')

            const events = {}

            const button = new ActionRowBuilder()
                .addComponents(
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setCustomId('button')
                        .setLabel('Down')
                        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),

                    new ButtonBuilder()
                        .setCustomId('button2')
                        .setLabel('Remove')
                        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary),
                )

            interaction.reply({ content: 'Creating event...', ephemeral: true });

            const name = interaction.options.get('create-event').value;
            console.log('name:', name);
            const startTime = interaction.options.get('start-time').value;
            console.log('startTime:', startTime);
            const place = interaction.options.get('where').value;
            console.log('location:', place);

            const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                .setColor('#CC8899')
                .setTitle(name)
                .setDescription('**Time: **' + startTime + `\n**Location: **` + place + `\n Attendees: `)
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Going: ', value: '' },
                )
                .setThumbnail(interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({ text: 'Created by: ' + interaction.user.tag });

            events[name] = {
                startTime: startTime,
                place: place,
                embed: embed,
                attendees: []
            };

            interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [button] });

            const collector = interaction.channel.createMessageCollector({ componentType: 'BUTTON' });

            collector.on('collect', async i => {

                const eventName = i.message.embeds[0].title;
                const eventInfo = events[eventName];

                if (i.customId === 'button') {
                    const existingEmbed = i.message.embeds[0];

                    const fields = existingEmbed.fields;

                    const fieldToUpdate = fields.find(field => field.name === 'Going: ');
                    fieldToUpdate.value = eventInfo.attendees.join(', ');

                    // add the user who clicked the button to the attendees array for the corresponding event
                    eventInfo.attendees.push(interaction.user.tag);

                    const updatedEmbed = new EmbedBuilder(existingEmbed).spliceFields(0, existingEmbed.fields.length, ...fields);
                    await i.update({ embeds: [updatedEmbed], components: [button] });
                }
            });
        }
})
```

This is pretty much what I tried. The idea is I use slash command to create an embed and the embed is sent to the channel and users can click on the button to show that they are attending. The embed should then update the "going" field with the user that clicked the button and when they click remove it should update the embed removing them from the going list (though remove has not been implemented, help is still appreciated).